# Java 1.7 bug?: inherited PropertyDescriptors for properties with generic return types lose attribute map

Tags: java, javabeans

As of Java 1.7, PropertyDescriptors obtained from BeanInfos for superclasses lose their attribute map *if the return type of the property takes generic paramaters*.  The test code below illustrates this behavior:

```
import java.beans.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class BeanInfoTest {

    public interface Super {

        public List<String> getSuperList();

        public void setSuperList(List<String> list);

        public String[] getSuperArray();

        public void setSuperArray(String[] array);
    }

    public interface Sub extends Super {

        public List<String> getSubList();

        public void setSubList(List<String> list);
    }

    public static class SuperBeanInfo extends SimpleBeanInfo {

        private PropertyDescriptor[] props = new PropertyDescriptor[2];

        public SuperBeanInfo() throws IntrospectionException {
            props[0] = new PropertyDescriptor("superList", Super.class);
            props[1] = new PropertyDescriptor("superArray", Super.class);

            props[0].setValue("superListAttribute", new Object());
            props[1].setValue("superArrayAttribute", new Object());
        }

        @Override
        public PropertyDescriptor[] getPropertyDescriptors() {
            return props;
        }
    }

    public static class SubBeanInfo extends SimpleBeanInfo {

        private PropertyDescriptor[] props = new PropertyDescriptor[1];

        public SubBeanInfo() throws IntrospectionException {
            props[0] = new PropertyDescriptor("subList", Sub.class);
            props[0].setValue("subListAttribute", new Object());
        }

        @Override
        public PropertyDescriptor[] getPropertyDescriptors() {
            return props;
        }

        @Override
        public BeanInfo[] getAdditionalBeanInfo() {
            try {
                return new BeanInfo[]{Introspector.getBeanInfo(Super.class)};
            } catch (IntrospectionException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testBeanInfo() throws IntrospectionException {

        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));

        PropertyDescriptor[] pds = Introspector.getBeanInfo(
                Sub.class).getPropertyDescriptors();

        List<String> allAttrNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (PropertyDescriptor pd : pds)
            allAttrNames.addAll(Collections.list(pd.attributeNames()));


        // always passes
        assertArrayEquals(pds, new PropertyDescriptor[]{
                    new PropertyDescriptor("subList", Sub.class),
                    new PropertyDescriptor("superArray", Super.class),
                    new PropertyDescriptor("superList", Super.class)
                });
        assertTrue(allAttrNames.contains("superArrayAttribute"));
        assertTrue(allAttrNames.contains("subListAttribute"));


        // passes under 1.6_43; fails under 1.7_07
        assertTrue(allAttrNames.contains("superListAttribute"));
    }
}
```

I realize this reads more like a bug report, so here are my questions:

- Is this truly a bug, I mean, did I overlook something in the spec or am I failing to follow some best practice that would avoid this situation altogether?
- If not, has anyone else encountered this problem and/or know of any workarounds that would allow one to continue using parameterized property types under Java 1.7?

Comment: When I run your SCCE under 1.7.0_17 it passes...

Comment: It fails for me under 1.6.0_24 and 1.7.0_09.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention my Java versions:  1.7.0_07  and  1.6.0_43

Comment: Sometimes you get so wrapped around the axle you forget to check the obvious; updated to 1.7_17 and the problem went away.  @Durandal, if you care to make it official you get the big green check...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this was a bug in the version I was running (1.7.0_07).  After updating to 1.7.0_17 the problem went way.